# Validar elemento no Selenium Webdriver

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, testes-automatizados, testes-funcionais

Estou com um determinado teste, onde programei para colocar umas matriculas e em seguida para ele da um click no botão (avançar) e depois no botão (concluir). Só que depende, pelo fato que tem algumas matriculas que não precisa de apertar o botão (avançar), e sim só no botão de (concluir). Queria saber como faço para ele entender que quando aparecer o botão de (avançar) ele de o click e em seguida click no de (concluir), e ao mesmo tempo quando não aparecer esse botão de (avançar), ele pule e vá para o botão de (concluir). Aguardo a resposta de alguém

Answer (score 0):

Quando eu precisei implementar uma lógica parecida com esta utilizei o `Expected Conditions` em conjunto com o WebDriverWait.

Utilizei o selenium para o python. Mas esta é a ideia.

Aquele número `10` é o tempo da espera.

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

elemento = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "idelemento")))
```

Espero ter ajudado.

Answer (score -1):

Edvaldo Torres,

Tente fazer o seguinte:

```
if(botaoAvancar.isDisplayed()){
   botaoAvancar.click();
   botaoConcluir.click();
}else{
   botaoConcluir.click();
}
```

isDisplayed() -> esse método valida se o elemento é exibido na tela ou não.

Abç.

Answer (score -1):

1- quando aparecer o botão de (avançar) ele de o click e em seguida click no de (concluir).
R: Pelo jeito você não colocou um time de espera após o click do botão avançar, coloque um time no botão depois que ele clicar em avançar, faça o sistema esperar mais um pouco e depois click em concluir.

2-Só que depende, pelo fato que tem algumas matriculas que não precisa de apertar o botão (avançar) e sim só no botão de (concluir). Então neste caso você tem que criar uma função no seu projeto que identifica qual matricula o botão de (avançar) pode ser clicado.

Exemplo matricula 12345677 essa matrícula não precisa ter o botão (avançar) apena concluir, então vc fará esse código

```
        IwebElement BtAvancar = Driver.GetElement(By.Id("IdBtnAvanar");
        IwebElement BtConcluir = Driver.GetElement(By.Id("IdBtnConcluir);

         public void AcaoBtn()
        {
            //Inserindo a mátricula que não precisa clicar no botão de avançar
           IwebElement CampoMatricula = Driver.GetElement(By.Id("CampoNumMatriula"));
           CampoMatricula.SendKeys("12345677");

           //Time de Espera
          System.Thrading.thread.sleep(2000);

          //Verifico se na minha página tem o botao de avançar
          if(driver.PageSource.Contains("Avançar"))
          {
             //Crie uma função que ignore o botão
          }

          if(driver.PageSorce.Contains("Concluir")
          {
                BtConcluir.Click();
          }

       }
```

Por enquanto essa é apenas um resposta simples, pois não sei como está o código da página,
se você puder colocar o código da página apenas para saber como esta escrito será mais fácil de ajudar e entender seu problema!